# Attempting weighted linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, weighted

I have data looking between air temperature and particulate matter 2.5 (PM2.5)

I have converted both data (spanning over 5 years, averaged daily data) to a time series, and performed a simple linear regression using code:

```
lm(TsIndira_Day_Temp ~ Ts_delhi_pm_averages)
```

issues being that there seems to be heteroscedasticity.

Here's the graph showing heteroscedasticity:
[image: Graph showing heteroscedasticity]

From initial research i thought the easiest way to amend this was to use a weighted regression using code:

```
rlm(Y ~ X, weights = 1/*)
```

But I don't know how to find the right weight to use. I have no idea how to even start figuring it out. Any help would be great.

Comment: If you are looking for `ts regression in R `resources, look at https://www.zeileis.org/teaching/AER/, and econometrics with r for an introduction.

Comment: https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/